# c++ CreateThread non static member without particular member name

Tags: c++, templates, winapi, non-static, createthread

I'm trying to create a thread with a non-static class member, like this:

```
template <class clName>
 DWORD WINAPI StartThread(PVOID ptr) {
   ((clName*)(ptr))->testf(); // this is static member name I want to be able use different names with the same function
   return 1;
 }

class Thread {
  private :
  HANDLE native_handle = 0;
  DWORD id = 0;
public :
  template <class T,class U>
  Thread(T U::*member,U* original); // I want to use different members with the same function
  bool run();
}

template<class T,class U>
Thread::Thread(T U::*member, U* original)
{
  native_handle = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)StartThread<U>,original, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);
}

bool Thread::run() {
  DWORD res = ResumeThread(native_handle);
  if (res == (DWORD)-1) return false;
  return true;
}


class testt {
public :
  void testf() {
    MessageBoxA(0, "working", "", 0);
  }
  void doIt() {
    Thread t(&testt::testf,this);
    t.run();
  }
};

int main() {
  testt tt;
  tt.doIt();
}
```

As you see, I can only run a particular member, so this method isn't portable and can't be used for any class or member.

I know I can use `std::thread` easily, but I'm working on a project that I shouldn't use any C++ runtime in, so I am creating wrappers for `new`/`delete`, threads, file I/O, etc. Otherwise, I always use `std::thread` and it's fantastic. In this project, I have to use Win32 API only.

Comment: Sounds like you should work to find a way to shed all those artificial constraints, so you can just write the natural working code.

Comment: If you have to cast the thread proc in the  CreateThread call you have declared it incorrectly.

Comment: @jesperJuhl I think there is a method as standard thread and boost thread can do this

Comment: @RichardCritten why incorrectly ?

Comment: Because `StartThread` should already be a `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. There is no point to defining it as anything different. Remove the cast and see if your function meets the required prototype. If it doesn't, make it fit. Using God's Hammer to force it to fit is a bad idea.

Comment: @user4581301 used the template to use any class as I was planning to use any member in any class

Comment: You need the static function as an abstraction, and the static function must fit the correct prototype. The static function can then call a member pointer that you have wrapped correctly with the appropriate parameters. Davis Herring has an idea worth following in their answer below.

Comment: I wonder... Do your assignment constraints prevent the use of a lambda expression? You may be able to use a lambda as your wrapper.

Comment: CreateThread can't run lambadas

Comment: You use the lambda to store the user's parameters and pass the lambda as the user pointer to `CreateThread`. `StartThread` executes the lambda. Note: I haven't tried this. It may not work without some standard library support, but if it does, the bulk of the messy work just went away.

Comment: When the compiler tells you that your function has the wrong signature, listen to it. Your cast tells a big lie to the compiler. Don't lie to the compiler

Comment: @RemyLebeau - in general - if we use member function declared as `__stdcall` with no explicit argument (implicit `this`) - this function will be binary compatible for `PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` and can be correct used for thread starting point. cast look like possible only through union here

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *CreateThread() expects a pointer to a standalone C style function* - this is not absolute true. `ULONG __stdcall testf()` member function - is ok for thread entry point. and can be used with `CreateThread`. like `union {
   LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pv;
   ULONG (__stdcall testt::* pfn)();
  };
  pfn = &testt::testf;
  CreateThread(0,0, pv, this, 0, 0);` (may be exist and another ways in modern c++)

Comment: @RbMb: That's formally undefined behavior on multiple levels, and totally unnecessary.  Compared to the cost of thread creation, one extra function call from a trampoline with the correct type to the "friendly" thread procedure is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with a winapi alternative for std::thread and works the same and is probably better

```
class letTest {
private :
  void pri(int u,float g, char l) {
      MessageBoxA(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

public :
  int doIt(int o) {
      auto t = thread(&letTest::pri, this,5,4.2,'k'); // works well with any number and type of parameters
      t.join();
      return 5;
  }
};
```

also with usual functions

```
void ltest(int i) {
   MessageBoxA(0, to_string(i).c_str(), 0, 0);
}
int main() {
   auto t = thread(ltest, 4);
   t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A template parameter can be a [pointer to member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), so you can augment `StartThread` that way and make `Thread::Thread`’s pointer-to-member parameter a template parameter.  You can’t supply explicit template arguments to a constructor template, so you’ll have to use a special “tag” argument to convey them:

```
template<class C,class T,T C::*P>
DWORD WINAPI StartThread(PVOID ptr) {
  (static_cast<C*>(ptr)->*P)();
  return 1;
}

template<class C,class T,T C::*P>
struct Tag {};

class Thread {
private :
  HANDLE native_handle = 0;
  DWORD id = 0;
public :
  template<class C,class T,T C::*P>
  Thread(Tag<C,T,P>,C*);
  bool run();
};

template<class C,class T,T C::*P>
Thread::Thread(Tag<C,T,P>,C* original)
{
  native_handle = CreateThread(0, 0, StartThread<C,T,P>,original,
                               CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);
}

bool Thread::run() {
  DWORD res = ResumeThread(native_handle);
  if (res == (DWORD)-1) return false;
  return true;
}


class testt {
public :
  void testf() {
    MessageBoxA(0, "working", "", 0);
  }
  void doIt() {
    Thread t(Tag<testt,void(),&testt::testf>(),this);
    t.run();
  }
};

int main() {
  testt tt;
  tt.doIt();
}
```

Note the `void()` function type as the member type `T`; simpler syntax is available in C++17 with `auto` in a template parameter’s type.

Or preserve it as a normal parameter by making a struct containing a `T*` and a `T::*` and passing a pointer to it as your `PVOID`.  The trick this way is that you’ll need to use type erasure to destroy that block correctly, or else use `reinterpret_cast` to store the pointers temporarily under fixed types (as already done for `StartThread`).

Comment: I get this error : 'type cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'

Comment: @dev65 since you did not show your new code, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong with it.

Comment: changed startthread to `template <class clName,class T, T clName::*member>
DWORD WINAPI StartRoutine(PVOID ptr) {
 
 ((clName*)(ptr))->*member();
 return 1;
}` then changed the constructor to :  `native_handle = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&StartRoutine<U,T,U::member>,original, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);`

Comment: @dev65: If you added `member` as a template parameter for the constructor as well, shouldn’t it just be `<U,T,member>`?

Comment: when using this `template<class T,class U, T U::*member>
Thread::Thread(T U::* memb, U* original)` no function matches : `Thread t(&testt::testf,this);`

Comment: @dev65: Ah, my mistake—I forgot that this was a constructor template.  You can’t provide explicit template parameters there; let me edit.

Comment: I almost got a solution , I'll post it as answer if no answers are being to be posted

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of the C++ runtime, like `std::thread` and `std::function`, your options are a bit limited.

Try something more like this:

```
template <class U>
class Thread {
private:
    HANDLE native_handle = 0;
    DWORD id = 0;
    U *object;
    void (U::*object_member)();

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID ptr);

public:
    Thread(void U::*member, U* obj);

    bool start();
};

template<class U>
DWORD WINAPI Thread<U>::ThreadProc(PVOID ptr) {
    Thread *t = static_cast<Thread*>(ptr);
    U *obj = t->object;
    void (U::*member)() = t->object_member;
    (obj->*member)();
    return 1;
}

template<class U>
Thread<U>::Thread(void U::*member, U* obj) :
    object_member(member), object(obj) {
    native_handle = CreateThread(0, 0, &ThreadProc, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);
}

template <class U>
bool Thread<U>::start() {
    return (ResumeThread(native_handle) != (DWORD)-1);
}

class testt {
public:
    void testf() {
        MessageBoxA(0, "working", "", 0);
    }

    void doIt() {
        Thread<testt> t(&testt::testf, this);
        t.start();
    }
};

int main() {
    testt tt;
    tt.doIt();
}
```

Otherwise, you may have to resort to something more like this:

```
class Thread {
private:
    HANDLE native_handle = 0;
    DWORD id = 0;
    void (*func)(void*);
    void *param;

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID ptr);

public:
    Thread(void (*f)(void*), void* p);
    bool start();
};

DWORD WINAPI Thread::ThreadProc(PVOID ptr) {
    Thread *t = static_cast<Thread*>(ptr);
    void (*func)(void*) = t->func;
    (*func)(t->param);
    return 1;
}

Thread::Thread(void (*f)(void*), void *p) :
    func(f), param(p) {
    native_handle = CreateThread(0, 0, &ThreadProc, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &id);
}

bool Thread::start() {
    return (ResumeThread(native_handle) != (DWORD)-1);
}

class testt {
private:
    static void proc(void *p) {
        static_cast<testt*>(p)->testf();
    }
public:
    void testf() {
        MessageBoxA(0, "working", "", 0);
    }
    void doIt() {
        Thread t(&testt::proc, this);
        t.start();
    }
};

int main() {
    testt tt;
    tt.doIt();
}
```

Comment: awesome solution for the current situation , keep in mind that I won't feel much limited as the project is quite small and I could use my old code with manual ThreadProc every time , but your code will save much time

Comment: @RemyLabeau when I used the code I got that void was illegal so I used int instead , then I got this error : 'Thread<testt>::Thread(Thread<testt> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__cdecl testt::* )(void)' to 'int testt::*

Comment: @dev65 I made some tweaks to the code. Try it again. I don't have access to a compiler until next week, or I would have checked it before I posted it

Comment: To be fully standard-compliant, `ThreadProc` needs to be `extern "C"` (language linkage is part of a function's type), which furthermore requires it to be a free function, not a static member.  To access private member data, `friend` can be safely used.

Answer (score -1):

application-defined function to be executed by the [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) must have signature:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

if we was use class member (non-static) function - it must have signature

```
class testt {
    ULONG WINAPI testf();
};
```

need remember that every non static member function got pointer to *this* as first parameter. simply we not explicit declare it. as result `ULONG WINAPI testf(/*testt* this*/);` exactly match to [*ThreadProc callback*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx) function. and we can use it as thread entry point.

> In this project, I have to use Win32 API only.

i not view for what need use wrappers for concrete this thread api, but code can look like:

```
template <class U>
class Thread 
{
    HANDLE _hThread;
    DWORD _id;

public :

    Thread() : _hThread(0) {}

    ~Thread() 
    { 
        if (_hThread) CloseHandle(_hThread);
    }

    ULONG Create(ULONG (WINAPI U::*member)(), U* This)
    {
        union {
            LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress;
            ULONG (WINAPI U::*_member)();
        };

        _member = member;

        if (_hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, lpStartAddress, This, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &_id))
        {
            return NOERROR;
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    ULONG run()
    {
        return ResumeThread(_hThread) == MAXULONG ? GetLastError() : NOERROR;
    }

    ULONG wait()
    {
        return WaitForSingleObject(_hThread, INFINITE);
    }
};


class testt {
    PCWSTR _txt, _caption;
public :

    testt(PCWSTR txt, PCWSTR caption) : _txt(txt), _caption(caption) { }

    ULONG WINAPI testf() {
        return MessageBox(0, _txt, _caption, 0);
    }

    void doIt() {

        Thread<testt> t;

        if (t.Create(&testt::testf, this) == NOERROR)
        {
            if (t.run() == NOERROR)
            {
                t.wait();
            }
        }
    }
};

void demo()
{

    testt o(L"text", L"caption");
    o.doIt();
}
```

---

however for compare code without template class, but direct start thread to class member function:

```
class testt {
    PCWSTR _txt, _caption;
public :

    testt(PCWSTR txt, PCWSTR caption) : _txt(txt), _caption(caption) { }

    ULONG WINAPI testf() {
        return MessageBox(0, _txt, _caption, 0);
    }

    void doIt() {

        union {
            LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress;
            ULONG (WINAPI testt::*pfn)();
        };

        pfn = &testt::testf;

        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, lpStartAddress, this, 0, 0))
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }
};

void demo()
{

    testt o(L"text", L"caption");
    o.doIt();
}
```

Comment: @dev65 - sorry not understand, where *WINAPI was the missing* (in my or your code or ?)

Comment: sorry , I was wrong and thought in another thing , the problem in Remy Lebeau code is that you can't cast the non static member to a callback function

Comment: as I said : 'Thread::Thread(Thread &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned int (__cdecl testt::* )(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__cdecl *)(void *)'

Comment: @dev65 - at first and main - thread entry point must be `__stdcall` - not `__cdecl`. at second - where you view conversion (type cast) in my code ? are my code not compile or wrong work ?

Comment: @dev65 - but why in this case you comment this here :) ? here exist sense do comment only about my implementation

Comment: That `union` trick doesn't work in C++.  And calling a function through a pointer of a different type is immediately undefined behavior -- C++ has no concept of compatible function types.

Comment: @BenVoigt - i compile and test this code in c++ (*cl.exe*) and all of course ok work. union member simply share the same memory (or register), because this all and ok. and by sense we need exactly `ULONG WINAPI testf();` signature for class member - if take to account hidden *this* pointer - real signature will be `ULONG WINAPI testf(testt* this);` - this is exactly `PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`

Comment: *And calling a function through a pointer of a different type* - this is not different but **same** type in my code

Comment: If it were the same type, you wouldn't be using the `union` trick (which is only legal in C anyway, C++ doesn't allow reading a different union member than the one last written to).  And seeing it work once, on a particular compiler version, with particular optimization settings, doesn't prove it is legal.  Undefined behavior is allowed to work some, all, or none of the time.

Comment: @BenVoigt - this is from compiler view different types, but from binary view - the same type - *__stdcall* function with one argument (*this*). and `union` "trick" the great work with all compilers and any level of optimization. with *cl.exe* especially because ms many time used union internals in windows in this manner

Comment: @RbMm: Really it works only with cl.exe, other compilers do break code that violates strict aliasing.  It's called "optimization instability".  And I think you're right that MS permits it because they have legacy code (Windows for sure and probably also Office and other apps) that they build with this compiler and isn't strictly conformant.

Comment: @BenVoigt - i special test this kind of code with another compilers also (gcc, clang, icc) on x86/x64 (where i understand asm code). test and in more complex case, with say `union { float a; int b; }`. and i not found any code breaks. if you can build example where this fail by sense - will be very interesting see it. and about "strict aliasing" - this is can be breaked(all examples which i view) when we **modify** memory via one alias and compiler can assume that memory was not modified by another. but here i use read only union members

Comment: i mean i use only that value of 2 pointers in union always the same. i not modify any memory by this pointers. can you build demo poc where this is fail (generate unexpected by sense code) ?

Comment: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun  The big problem with optimization-unstable code is that often nothing goes wrong until you install a new compiler version and then all your bugs suddenly start to manifest.

Comment: And see where they say "this code produced no output" at http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-naked

Comment: @BenVoigt - really this is not true - at first `double` is 8 byte when `int` - 4. need use `float` with `int` or `long long` with `double` - about "this code produced no output" - look and test code like https://godbolt.org/g/qZ3vvT

Comment: @BenVoigt - or say this https://godbolt.org/g/KVbyv4. can you in opposite build poc where was unexcepted, wrong code when used union ? but not modify any memory location via one union member and then read this memory location via another member (alias). try build code where we use only that 2 union members (with the same size) always have the **same** value - only this i use

Comment: The code exhibits undefined behavior. You cannot prove absence of undefined behavior by looking at the output of compilers. To understand this, you need to understand, why undefined behavior exists at all: It gives compiler writers flexibility in implementing their optimizers. Looking at compiler output can only determine, that any particular compiler hasn't taken advantage of the freedom it has, to produce optimized code that collides with your (undue) expectations. That surely will change one day, or when code is placed in a different code context.

Comment: @IInspectable - my code based on very simply thing - the union share memory. all union members have the same address (this already again clear stated in latest c++20 standard :)) ) and as result we can say that value of `pfn` and `lpStartAddress` is always equal

Comment: C++20 isn't a thing yet. Regardless, if you know this to be safe in C++20, add a reference to documentation to this proposed answer to make it clear, that it is currently unsafe, but will be safe in a future revision of the C++ programming language.

Comment: @IInspectable - i already many time paste in discuss with you very old reference from msdn - *All members are stored in the same memory space and start at the same address. The stored value is overwritten each time a value is assigned to a different member.* in middle  formal c++ docs say that layout of union is implementation details. and now, in latest draft - again that All members  start at the same address

Comment: @IInspectable - *As a consequence, all non-static data members of a
union object have the same address.* - look for [n4741.pdf](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4741.pdf) - 12.3 Unions - 2. and *A union object and its non-static data
members are pointer-interconvertible*

Comment: No one was challenging, that they weren't. And still, the strict aliasing rule allows compilers to not even attempt to read the value you stored through a different member, because the optimizer decided, that nothing can possibly have changed, and uses the cached value from the initialization. The optimizer is correct in doing this, because it is allowed to. Your proposed code breaks, once it meets an optimizer that does this.

Comment: @IInspectable - strict aliasing can on or off by compiler option. this is first. and from generic view - anyway this 2 pointers stored in memory (stack) or some non volatile register. compiler anyway need pass something to `CreateThread` as parameter. no another way. as result it anyway need be read from memory or use this non volatile register. and got value which i set by `pfn = &testt::testf;`

Comment: @IInspectable - [*The details of that allocation are implementation-defined*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) vs *all non-static data members of a
union object have the same address.* :))

Comment: [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)

Comment: @IInspectable - at first on some compilers this option can be off - `-fno-strict-aliasing`. for *CL* compiler this is always off how i know. here no this strict aliasing at all. and what i do here in poc - https://godbolt.org/z/k0ndo6 - are you try to say that optimizator drop `pfn = &testt::testf;` line without warning ? only here can be code broken. if this line is executed - all ok

Comment: @IInspectable - interesting that all articles about Type Punning have concrete examples how code is defeated with aggressive optimization, but  i not view how is defeat https://godbolt.org/z/7ykklI now. i already not say about cl not support this strict aliassing at all and another compilers support off it. but much more interesting discuss about addreff/relese - why you not reply here ?

Comment: @IInspectable - even better this - https://godbolt.org/z/MG28HZ - where the whole essence is preserved. i can not found under any compiler and optimization where this is breaked, already not say about *cl*